# Como responder 500 perguntas em 12h?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, localização, medalhas

A descrição da medalha Luminar diz o seguinte:

> **Luminar** - Editou e respondeu 500 pergunta (em um intervalo de 12h, resposta com pontuação > 0)

Seria essa a medalha mais difícil de conseguir? Ou o texto está apenas mal escrito? Rs..

O texto dela em inglês <sup>(que também não é grandes coisas)</sup>, está assim:

> **Illuminator** -   Edited and answered 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

Na verdade para conseguir essa medalha ninguém precisa responder 500 perguntas em 12h, e como se não bastasse ainda ter que editar a pergunta que respondeu e pontuar na resposta. O que precisa ser feito é responder e editar a pergunta, as duas ações devem ocorrer dentro de um período de 12h independente se você prefere responder primeiro ou editar primeiro, sua resposta precisa ter pontuação positiva, e o conjunto de todas essas ações precisa ser feito 500 vezes, não importa quanto tempo isso leve.

Conversando no chat hoje e também nos comentários da resposta do JorgeB, pude concluir que o texto está sendo mal interpretado por várias pessoas, creio eu que seria o caso de melhorá-lo.

<sub>PS: E ainda tem que colocar "pergunta" no plural, para essa e para a medalha Aprimorador. Por isso da tag [`localização`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o).</sub>

Sugestões?

Comment: No original também poderia ser melhorado.

Comment: Concordo com o @Bacco, Math abre lá no metão! :P

Comment: @Bacco Tem razão, não é o melhor dos textos, mas eles que se virem...

Comment: A discussão original (em inglês) para quem quiser acompanhar o que foi conversado: [New three-tiered badge idea: Explainer -> Refiner -> Illuminator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239898/229289)

Comment: Mostre um texto explicativo das medalhas em inglês que dê para entender sem sair fumaça do cérebro e você ganha uma camiseta (a SE vai mandar, não eu :D)

Comment: Um adendo fora do escopo da questão mas editar e responder 500 perguntas com "qualidade" não é meio impossível? porque pelos meus cálculos (60*12)/500 = 1.44 min por pergunta.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique lê de novo a pergunta do Math, onde diz "Na verdade para conseguir essa medalha ninguém precisa responder 500 perguntas em 12h,...".

Comment: Tá atualizado (pras 3 medalhas). Usei a resposta do Jorge B., que tinha mais votos. Vai pro ar no próximo build.

Answer (score 8):

> Editou e respondeu a 500 perguntas (as 2 ações com intervalo de 12
>   horas, resposta com pontuação > 0)

Comment: Posso estar sendo chato, mas retiraria o "a". `Editou e respondeu 500 perguntas(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

> Editou 500 perguntas até 12 horas antes ou depois de responder, e a resposta tem pontuação positiva.

Comment: É antes ou depois de responder?

Comment: @JorgeB. Tanto faz, até 12 horas antes ou 12 horas depois.

Answer (score 3):

Com vista a detalhar sem perder informação relevante:

> Editou e respondeu um total de 500 perguntas (ambas as ações ocorridas por pergunta, num intervalo máximo de 12 horas, tendo a resposta recebido pontuação > 0)

Comment: É bem preciso mesmo. Eu só acrescentaria uma vírgula depois de "ocorridas".

Answer (score 2):

> Editou e respondeu a 500 perguntas (ambas as ações realizadas no
>   intervalo de 12 horas em respostas com pontuação maior que zero).